# OpenID Null SSL context error

Tags: ssl, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, openid-connect

The error below comes up when we stage our Bluemix Liberty app, about 1 in every 10 times. If you try and authenticate, after redirection from the OpenID provider you get a popup asking you for a username and password, which seems to have no effect. Restarting the app fixes it.

> CWWKS1707E: The OpenID Connect client [NTBhZGQ4MWMtN2Y5Ni00] was
>   unable to create an SSL context due to [CWWKS1707E: The OpenID Connect
>   client [NTBhZGQ4MWMtN2Y5Ni00] was unable to create an SSL context due
>   to [Null ssl conext]. Ensure that your SSL feature is properly
>   configured.]. Ensure that your SSL feature is properly configured.

This may be related to injecting the OpenID Client configuration from a user-provided service in our server.xml:

```
<openidConnectClient 
    httpsRequired="true" id="blueid" includeIdTokenInSubject="true" 
    authorizationEndpointUrl="https://${cloud.services.${env.openidservice}.connection.domain}/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/authorize" 
    tokenEndpointUrl="https://${cloud.services.${env.openidservice}.connection.domain}/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/token" 
    issuerIdentifier="https://${cloud.services.${env.openidservice}.connection.domain}" 
    clientId="${cloud.services.${env.openidservice}.connection.clientid}" 
    clientSecret="${cloud.services.${env.openidservice}.connection.clientsecret}"
    mapIdentityToRegistryUser="false" scope="openid" signatureAlgorithm="RS256" 
    trustAliasName="${cloud.services.${env.openidservice}.connection.certificate}" 
    trustStoreRef="validationKeyStore" 
    userIdentityToCreateSubject="uniqueSecurityName"> 
</openidConnectClient>
```

The injection must be working because the clientId mentioned in the error message is correct. Not sure why the SSL context would be null. I have tried with and without an SSL element in the server.xml, but the problem still occurs.

Does anyone know what the cause might be?

Answer (score 0):

From your openid connect client configuration, you do not have SSL configuration defined for openid connect client, so openid connect client is using the server's default SSL configuration. To have a definitive behavior, I would recommend that you explicitly configure SSL for openid connect client by adding "sslRef=" into openidConnectClient, and your ssl configuration must contain a trust store that has openid provider'scertificate.

Comment: can you share your server.xml file with me?